# kendo-ui-angular2 Chart - Interactive Guided line

Tags: kendo-ui-angular2

Is there a way to show the interactive guided line on Kendo Angular 2 chart?
I want to show the guided line like the one in the other chart

1. Kendo Chart : http://plnkr.co/edit/8aXk9mxCJldFWKzWL65W?p=preview
2. Other Chart : http://plnkr.co/edit/5tN6Ku?p=previ

   import { Component } from '@angular/core';
   @Component({
   selector: 'my-app',
   template: 
   `<kendo-chart>
     <kendo-chart-title text="Units sold"></kendo-chart-title>
     <kendo-chart-category-axis>
         <kendo-chart-category-axis-item
             [categories]="['Jan', 'Feb', 'Mar', 'Apr', 'May', 'Jun', 'Jul']"
             [title]="{ text: 'Months' }">
         </kendo-chart-category-axis-item>
     </kendo-chart-category-axis>
     <kendo-chart-tooltip format="{0}" shared="true"></kendo-chart-tooltip>
     <kendo-chart-series>
       <kendo-chart-series-item [type]="type" 
                                [data]="[123, 276, 310, 212, 240, 156, 98,144, 
     190]" 
                                [markers] ="markers" 
                                [style]="style" 
                                [width]="width"
                                [name]="'Start Amount'">
       </kendo-chart-series-item>
       <kendo-chart-series-item [type]="type" 
                                [data]="[165, 210, 287, 144, 190, 167, 212, 
      276, 310 ]" 
                                [markers] ="markers" 
                                [style]="style" 
                                [width]="width"
                                 [name]="'Scaled Amount'">
       </kendo-chart-series-item>
       <kendo-chart-series-item [type]="type" 
                                [data]="[56, 140, 195, 46, 123, 78, 95,212, 
      240]" 
                                [markers] ="markers" 
                                [style]="style" 
                                [width]="width"
                                [name]="'Lifted Amount'">
       </kendo-chart-series-item>
       </kendo-chart-series>
     </kendo-chart>`

   })
    export export class AppComponent { 
    type='line';
    style ='smooth';
    width ='1';
    markers = {
     visible:false
    };
   }

Thanks,
Raj

Answer (score 0):

I got this answered by telerik support.

We can enable the Interactive guiding line(vertical line) via the [CategoryAxisItemComponent crosshair](http://www.telerik.com/kendo-angular-ui/components/charts/api/CategoryAxisItemComponent/#toc-crosshair) input.